# How can compile scope ngClick in directive on ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive, in this directive we compile **ngRepeat** as you see.

**my problem is** :

I can't call $scope.delete() from controller, and i don't know how can compile it in my directive.

> **Note:** run the sample

```js
        var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            var root = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

            $scope.list = [];

            $http.get(root + "/users").success(function (data) {
                $scope.list = data;
            });

          ///i can't call this scope
            $scope.delete = function (item) {
                alert("delete called");
            }
        });

        app.directive("mydata", ["$compile", "$filter", function ($compile, $filter) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {
                    list: "="
                },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    var ngRepeat = element.find(".repeat").attr("ng-repeat", "item in list");
                    $compile(ngRepeat)(scope);
                }
            }
        }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="parent" mydata data-list="list">
        <li class="repeat">
            {{item.name}}
            <button ng-click="delete()">delete</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why u are trying to do stuffs like this but a quick solution for your code is to compile the ngRepeat with the controller's scope instead of the directive the scope;

```
$compile(ngRepeat)(scope.$parent);
```

Your delete() won't fire since u are creating an isolated scope on your `my-data` directive. The delete() method will not get inherited.

For more conception about isolated scope and scope inheritance, check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: Hi, tnx to you, that was helpful, in fact i want use it in my dynamic table.